# Bookshelf hasMany().through() argument ignored

Tags: bookshelf.js

I have a `Course` model that is pretty conventional. I also have a `Book` model that is not. Between them, I have a `CourseMaterial` model.

I'm trying to configure my `Course` model such that `Course.hasMany('Book').through('CourseMaterial')`, but because of some unconventional stuff, I need to specify each key. The tables join like so:

- The `courses` table has an `id`.
- The `courseMaterials` table as a FK, `course_id` that references `courses.id`.
- The `course_materials` table has an `identifier` field that, for the purposes of this discussion, contains a ISBN value.
- The `books` table has a `isbn` table whose value would match what's in `course_materials.identifier`.

In my `Course` model, my relationship looks like this:

```
books: function() {
    return this.hasMany('Book')
        .through('CourseMaterial', 'isbn', 'identifier');
},
```

The generated SQL seems to ignore the third parameter:

```
SELECT `books`.*, 
       `course_materials`.`id` AS `_pivot_id`, 
       `course_materials`.`course_id` AS `_pivot_course_id` 
  FROM `books` 
        INNER JOIN `course_materials` 
                ON `course_materials`.`id` = `books`.`isbn`
```

Why is it trying to join on `course_materials.id` rather than on `course_materials.identifier`? Am I misreading the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an existing issue as per below link:

https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/673

So the third argument is ignored by bookshelf library.

Solution is to build the custom SQL using knex as the way you want defining each step as follows:

```
knex('books').innerJoin('CourseMaterial', 'CourseMaterial.identifier', 'books.isbn')

OR (in case you want to do projection on results)

knex('books').select(['books.id', 'books.bookname'])
.innerJoin('CourseMaterial', 'CourseMaterial.identifier', 'books.isbn')
```